# preg_replace create two different variables by spliting another one

Tags: javascript, php

I am using a POST XMLHttpRequest in order to send data to a PHP script. The part of the javascript code is this:

```
function phppost(a, b){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("POST", "phppostexample.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.send("send="+a+""+b);
}
```

And the part of the PHP code is this:

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
    $code = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['send']);
    $name = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#', '', $_POST['send']);
```

The problem is that I want the two variables I will give (`a` and `b`), to be become `$code` and `$name` but when I run `phppost(43365, "Hello World 43");` The PHP script gives me `$code` as 4336943 and `$name` as 43369HelloWorld43. How can I make the PHP scriipt to give me `$code` as 43369 and `$name` as Hello World 43 (with gaps between the words)? Thanks in advance

Comment: making it hard on yourself by sending both as one parameter, send them as `name` and `code` instead of concatenating into `send`

Comment: @charlietfl So you mean this: if(isset($_POST['code'])) { if(isset($_POST['name'])) {} } ? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really just elaborating on @charlietfl's comment:

```
function phppost(a, b){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("POST", "phppostexample.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.send("code="+a+"&name="+b);
}
```

then

```
if(isset($_POST['code'])) {
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seperating the data into 2 parameters would be best.

You could accomplish this though with a regex if the data structure is consistent.

```
$a = '43365Hello World 43';
preg_match('#^(\d+)?([a-z].*)$#i', $a, $data);
$code = $data[1];
$name = $data[2];
echo $code . "\n";
echo $name . "\n";
```

PHP Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1831fcef83a75ed94dcf54d9b88d1231714bf349

Regex101:https://regex101.com/r/fI6lO3/1

This is pretty loose though, just starts with a number, then has a letter. The grouping separates at the first letter. If your codes are <s>alphanumeric</s> anything but numeric this won't work.